# Unexpected output for integer values used as counter

Tags: c, initialization, getchar

While writing what should be a very simple program ( out of K&R C book ), I get some output which I do not understand. If I `EOF` right away, `nl_count` is correctly 0, but `space_count` is always 32767 ( half of maximum `int` range), and `tab_count` is a large value ( usually very high or very low ).

When I initialize all variables to 0, then the program works correctly. What am I missing here?

```
 10 int main(void)
 11 {
 12         int tab_count, space_count, nl_count;
 13 
 14         //tab_count = space_count = nl_count = 0;
 15 
 16         int c;
 17         while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
 18                 if( c == '\t' )
 19                         tab_count++;
 20                 if( c == ' ' )
 21                         space_count++;
 22                 if( c == '\n' )
 23                         nl_count++;
 24         }
 25 
 26         printf("\n");
 27         printf("TABS = %d\n", tab_count);
 28         printf("SPACES = %d\n", space_count);
 29         printf("NEWLINES = %d\n", nl_count);
 30 
 31         return 0;
 32 }
```

*Inputs and Outputs:*

Here is another input, which again correctly outputs 3 for newlines, but junk for tabs, and 32767 for spaces.

> (space)(space)(space)\t\t\t\n\n\n

```
TABS = 441446448
SPACES = 32767
NEWLINES = 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I initialize all vars to 0, then the program works correctly. What am I missing here?

`tab_count`, `space_count` and `nl_count;` are *automatic storage* variables. If you don't initialize them to `0`, they have a *indeterminate* values. Reading from them is technically *undefined behaviour* (UB). Since you're incrementing their value before initializing them, you are invoking UB. One manifestation of UB is to produce seemingly nonsensical values.

Comment: It was my understanding that those variables are initialized to 0 in C

Comment: automatic storage variables are *indeterminate*. “unspecified” implies that these variables have one of several possible values, which is not the case: using them is undefined behavior and can make anything happen. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined https://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/ http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/

Comment: @PascalCuoq I thought in C they take an unspecified value. I know reading from them is UB in C++, but I thought this was not the case in C. Am I wrong? If so I will fix this.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah wait, IIRC C does say something about trap representations, etc.

Comment: @juanchopanza In C90, it's explicitly UB. In C99, yes, there is the part about trap representations which is ambiguous when you know the types do not have trap representations (compilers still optimize as if it was UB). In C11 it's explicitly said that it's UB if you have not taken their addresses.

Comment: Why did space_count always have the value 32767 and nl_count have the correct value?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks. I have re-phrased the answer.

Comment: @user3370603 That is *undefined behaviour*. Think of it as "anything can happen".

Comment: @PascalCuoq I tried quoting the standard  itself regarding this. Hope that makes it clear. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Only Extern and Static variables are initialized to 0 by default. All other variables have an indeterminate value, which is why you have to initialize them to 0 before using them.

Answer (score 2):

I can't resist.

> When I initialize all vars to 0, then the program works correctly.
>   What am I missing here?

You are missing that you must initialise all the variables to zero.

Maybe what you are really missing is the fact that C programs that break the rules can have undefined/unspecified behaviour. This mean they can appear to work, or partially work, even though they are incorrect.

Comment: Possibly It's because I'm half asleep right now, but I thought variables in the scope of main function are automatically initialized to 0. That's my issue, why do I have to explicitly initialize them?

Comment: Nope, true of global and static variables though.

Comment: @user3370603 "why do I have to explicitly initialize them" Have you been reading the answers?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, thanks to everyone. I've known that before. I was assuming that main was special for some reason.

Comment: @user3370603 The `main` function is a function like any other. There is absolutely nothing special about this function apart from the fact that it is called when the program is run.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, when you define automatic local variables, they are not initialized to any value implicitly. You have to initialize them *explicitly*. Otherwise, the content of those variables are garbage and indeterminate.

Reference: `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized  explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Next, without a *write* (atleast, the initialization), if you try to *use* (read) the value, it invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Reference: `C11`, Annex §J.2

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

Then, to answer

> *When I initialize all vars to 0, then the program works correctly*

Yes, ofcourse, because, that way, there is no UB.

So, in your code, you **have** to change

```
 int tab_count, space_count, nl_count;
```

to

```
 int tab_count = 0;
 int space_count = 0;
 int nl_count = 0;
```